# I need to measure liquid temperature down to -80C

Tags: measurement, temperature, thermocouple

Building a device that will sit inside a liquid that will be a max of -80C and trying to figure out what my options are for measuring the temperature.

I was thinking a thermocouple but not sure if that's a good approach.

What have you used that you liked?

Thank you

Comment: "Max" or "min"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple shows low temperature capabilities. http://omega.com have very useful information.

Comment: @EugeneSh lower-bound needs to be -80C.  Upper bound is not crucial